# R: Splitting a string into multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, split, strsplit

I am working with the following column string in a dataframe

```
s <- "[08/26/2021 06:58:12 260] - MacId: 40_E3_D6_CA_56_5C RSSI: -92"
```

I would like to split that somehow into the following columns

- df$Datetime  = 08/26/2021 06:58:12 260
- df$MacId      = 40_E3_D6_CA_56_5C
- df$RSSI       = -92

Is there a function which can do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `strcapture` and pass the pattern to extract the data required.

```
s <- "[08/26/2021 06:58:12 260] - MacId: 40_E3_D6_CA_56_5C RSSI: -92"

result <- strcapture('\\[(.*)\\] - MacId: (.*) RSSI: (.*)', s, 
           proto = list(Datetime = character(), MacId = character(), 
                        RSSI = numeric()))

result
#                 Datetime             MacId RSSI
#1 08/26/2021 06:58:12 260 40_E3_D6_CA_56_5C  -92
```

If the string is present in a dataframe the same regex pattern can be used in `tidyr::extract` -

```
tidyr::extract(data.frame(s), s, c('Datetime', 'MacId', 'RSSI'), 
               "\\[(.*)\\] - MacId: (.*) RSSI: (.*)")
```