# R: splitting a textfile into a workable dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, text, data-preprocessing

I am working with a text file containing localization data. Every 5 minutes there are multiple reports which can result into a calculated zone. If it resolves the zone it outputs a identified room ID (4260 and 4256 in the example):

```
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 600] - TagId: 4194912 Identified RoomId:4260
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 616] - TagId: 4194912 Last Monitorid:4195283
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 631] - TagId: 4194912 After RoomId:2199
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 631] - Localization RoomId: 2199
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 663] - TagId: 4194912 Reporting RoomId:2199
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 663] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_A4 RSSI: -72
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 678] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C7_86_54 RSSI: -82
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 678] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_89_3C RSSI: -45
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 694] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_22 RSSI: -80
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 709] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_12 RSSI: -60
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 709] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_A8 RSSI: -83
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 709] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_90 RSSI: -89
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 709] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_2E RSSI: -54
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 913] - MacId: 40_E3_D6_CA_56_5C RSSI: -92
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 913] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_52 RSSI: -92
[08/14/2021 05:05:59 928] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_B8 RSSI: -80
[08/14/2021 05:06:00 288] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_A4 RSSI: -72
[08/14/2021 05:06:00 288] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C7_86_54 RSSI: -82
[08/14/2021 05:06:00 288] - MacId: 40_E3_D6_CA_57_0A RSSI: -90
[08/14/2021 05:06:00 288] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_89_3C RSSI: -45
[08/14/2021 05:06:00 413] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_90 RSSI: -90
[08/14/2021 05:06:00 413] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_12 RSSI: -60
[08/14/2021 05:06:00 428] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_22 RSSI: -80
[08/14/2021 05:06:00 428] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_A8 RSSI: -83
[08/14/2021 05:06:00 428] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_2E RSSI: -55
[08/14/2021 05:11:00 974] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_A4 RSSI: -72
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 006] - TagId: 4194912 Identified RoomId:4256
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 021] - TagId: 4194912 Last Monitorid:4195283
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 037] - TagId: 4194912 After RoomId:2199
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 052] - Localization RoomId: 2199
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 084] - TagId: 4194912 Reporting RoomId:2199
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 084] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C7_86_54 RSSI: -83
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 084] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_78 RSSI: -90
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 099] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_89_3C RSSI: -45
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 349] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_12 RSSI: -60
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 349] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_2E RSSI: -55
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 349] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_A8 RSSI: -84
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 349] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_90 RSSI: -89
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 365] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_22 RSSI: -80
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 474] - MacId: 40_E3_D6_CA_56_5C RSSI: -93
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 490] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_52 RSSI: -90
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 490] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_BE RSSI: -89
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 802] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_A4 RSSI: -72
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 802] - MacId: 40_E3_D6_CA_57_0A RSSI: -90
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 802] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_89_3C RSSI: -45
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 802] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_78 RSSI: -89
[08/14/2021 05:11:01 802] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C7_86_54 RSSI: -82
[08/14/2021 05:11:02 006] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_90 RSSI: -89
[08/14/2021 05:11:02 006] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_22 RSSI: -80
[08/14/2021 05:11:02 021] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_A8 RSSI: -84
[08/14/2021 05:11:02 021] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_2E RSSI: -55
[08/14/2021 05:11:02 021] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_12 RSSI: -60
[08/14/2021 05:11:02 115] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_52 RSSI: -91
[08/14/2021 05:11:02 115] - MacId: F0_5C_19_C6_88_BE RSSI: -88
```

I would like to end up with data in the form of:

[image: Image of desired dataframe]

In case the RoomId is not resolved in the 5 minute timeframe (from the raw text file) the column RoomId can just be NA.

A very helpful member already showed how to split the columns in the right manner ([R: Splitting a string into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68995496/r-splitting-a-string-into-multiple-columns/68995591#68995591))

So the main question is: *How can I structure this raw text file in a way similar to the image where it is a workable dataframe although not all the lines from the raw text file are similar?*

Comment: When `Identified RoomID` resolves, is it applicable to the prior or following MAC addresses in some regular fashion? It appears above that `Reporting RoomID:2199` doesn't resolve in this time window. If not resolved, how can MAC addresses be reliably characterized?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. 
So basically a set can be grouped based on the date time, so in the example either 05:05:59& 05:06:00 or 05:11:01/ 05:11:02. 

In the case of the example that would mean the resolved room ID is documented first and the MAC adresses are following.

Comment: Then might you not extend Ronak's example to `Identified RoomID:`, as this seems to indicate `resolved`. Is this pulling from a kernel log of say classroom wifi services provided?

Comment: Yes I did try that as well indeed, but unfurtunately that resulted into NAs everywhere. Perhaps I wrote the code incorrectly:
`result <- strcapture('\\[(.*)\\] - MacId: (.*) RSSI: (.*) RoomId: (.*)', dataframe, 
                     proto = list(Datetime = character(), MacId = character(), 
                                  RSSI = numeric(), RoomId = numeric()))`

Comment: This probably won't be helpful, but `Identified RoomID:` instead of `Room ID:`. Thru time, you have two steps, first which is identified, `resolved`, thence applying that to the following MAC(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data is stored in a text file called `'temp.txt'`, you can read it using `readLines`. Keep only the rows which has `MacId` and `RSSI` values and to get the `RoomId` keep the `'Identified RoomId'` row as well. Split the data in sets and from each set extract `Datetime`, `MacId` and `RSSI` using the code from previous post and extract the room id by removing everything until `RoomId`. You can combine the output into one dataframe.

```
data <- readLines('temp.txt')
req_data <- grep('MacId.*RSSI|Identified RoomId', data, value = TRUE)
result <- do.call(rbind, by(req_data, cumsum(grepl('Identified', req_data)), 
          function(x) {
  room_id <- sub('.*RoomId:\\s*', '', x[1])
  cbind(strcapture('\\[(.*)\\] - MacId: (.*) RSSI: (.*)', x[-1], 
             proto = list(Datetime = character(), MacId = character(), 
                          RSSI = numeric())), RoomId = room_id)
}))
rownames(result) <- NULL
```

For the text data shared I get output as -

```
result
                  Datetime             MacId RSSI RoomId
1  08/14/2021 05:05:59 663 F0_5C_19_C6_88_A4  -72   4260
2  08/14/2021 05:05:59 678 F0_5C_19_C7_86_54  -82   4260
3  08/14/2021 05:05:59 678 F0_5C_19_C6_89_3C  -45   4260
4  08/14/2021 05:05:59 694 F0_5C_19_C6_88_22  -80   4260
5  08/14/2021 05:05:59 709 F0_5C_19_C6_88_12  -60   4260
6  08/14/2021 05:05:59 709 F0_5C_19_C6_88_A8  -83   4260
7  08/14/2021 05:05:59 709 F0_5C_19_C6_88_90  -89   4260
8  08/14/2021 05:05:59 709 F0_5C_19_C6_88_2E  -54   4260
9  08/14/2021 05:05:59 913 40_E3_D6_CA_56_5C  -92   4260
10 08/14/2021 05:05:59 913 F0_5C_19_C6_88_52  -92   4260
11 08/14/2021 05:05:59 928 F0_5C_19_C6_88_B8  -80   4260
12 08/14/2021 05:06:00 288 F0_5C_19_C6_88_A4  -72   4260
13 08/14/2021 05:06:00 288 F0_5C_19_C7_86_54  -82   4260
14 08/14/2021 05:06:00 288 40_E3_D6_CA_57_0A  -90   4260
15 08/14/2021 05:06:00 288 F0_5C_19_C6_89_3C  -45   4260
16 08/14/2021 05:06:00 413 F0_5C_19_C6_88_90  -90   4260
17 08/14/2021 05:06:00 413 F0_5C_19_C6_88_12  -60   4260
18 08/14/2021 05:06:00 428 F0_5C_19_C6_88_22  -80   4260
19 08/14/2021 05:06:00 428 F0_5C_19_C6_88_A8  -83   4260
20 08/14/2021 05:06:00 428 F0_5C_19_C6_88_2E  -55   4260
21 08/14/2021 05:11:00 974 F0_5C_19_C6_88_A4  -72   4260
22 08/14/2021 05:11:01 084 F0_5C_19_C7_86_54  -83   4256
23 08/14/2021 05:11:01 084 F0_5C_19_C6_88_78  -90   4256
24 08/14/2021 05:11:01 099 F0_5C_19_C6_89_3C  -45   4256
25 08/14/2021 05:11:01 349 F0_5C_19_C6_88_12  -60   4256
26 08/14/2021 05:11:01 349 F0_5C_19_C6_88_2E  -55   4256
27 08/14/2021 05:11:01 349 F0_5C_19_C6_88_A8  -84   4256
28 08/14/2021 05:11:01 349 F0_5C_19_C6_88_90  -89   4256
29 08/14/2021 05:11:01 365 F0_5C_19_C6_88_22  -80   4256
30 08/14/2021 05:11:01 474 40_E3_D6_CA_56_5C  -93   4256
31 08/14/2021 05:11:01 490 F0_5C_19_C6_88_52  -90   4256
32 08/14/2021 05:11:01 490 F0_5C_19_C6_88_BE  -89   4256
33 08/14/2021 05:11:01 802 F0_5C_19_C6_88_A4  -72   4256
34 08/14/2021 05:11:01 802 40_E3_D6_CA_57_0A  -90   4256
35 08/14/2021 05:11:01 802 F0_5C_19_C6_89_3C  -45   4256
36 08/14/2021 05:11:01 802 F0_5C_19_C6_88_78  -89   4256
37 08/14/2021 05:11:01 802 F0_5C_19_C7_86_54  -82   4256
38 08/14/2021 05:11:02 006 F0_5C_19_C6_88_90  -89   4256
39 08/14/2021 05:11:02 006 F0_5C_19_C6_88_22  -80   4256
40 08/14/2021 05:11:02 021 F0_5C_19_C6_88_A8  -84   4256
41 08/14/2021 05:11:02 021 F0_5C_19_C6_88_2E  -55   4256
42 08/14/2021 05:11:02 021 F0_5C_19_C6_88_12  -60   4256
43 08/14/2021 05:11:02 115 F0_5C_19_C6_88_52  -91   4256
44 08/14/2021 05:11:02 115 F0_5C_19_C6_88_BE  -88   4256
```